# TypeScript handbook issue?

Tags: typescript

I was reading the [Advanced Type section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) of the TypeScript handbook
and it seems to me that the descriptions of intersection types and union types are interchanged:

> **Intersection Types**
>
> An intersection type combines multiple types into one[...]

This is what I would expect to be a union type:

> **Union Types**
>
> If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.

Common to all members sounds like an intersection.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: I always confuse them as well, the naming is less then ideal, but it's not a handbook issue, this is the official typescript naming for them.

Comment: No it's correct, you're just thinking about it differently. It depends on what the elements of the set are. Are they the types? Are they the properties of the types?

Answer (score 0):

In structural type system, type can be defined as a set of all values that conform to that type. For example, if you have

```
type A = {a: string}
```

then the set of values conforming to `A` is a set of all objects that have property named `a` and that property type is `string`.

If you have

```
type B = {b: number}
```

and then

```
type AB = A & B
```

you just described `AB` is a set of all objects that have both properties `a` and `b` with correct types, in other words, an intersection of sets `A` and `B`. So it happens that intersection type of object types must have all properties from both types, and set of its properties is a union - this is where the confusion comes from.

if you define a type as a collection of properties then indeed definition of union and intersection is switched, but this kind of definition is more limited - it will not allow to define intersection and union for all types. There are types which are not objects (for example, `undefined`) , also some types have properties that could not be described as properties of an object - for example, objects of function types are callable.

Comment: Thanks artem for the clarification! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

The terminology is not TypeScript specific. Still it's confusing!

These two kind of types are seen complementary:

> "Intersection types [are] the logical complement of union types. A union type `A | B` represents an entity that has either type `A` or type `B`, whereas an intersection type `A & B` represents an entity that has both type `A` and type `B`.", *[Anders Hejlsberg's pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622)*.

Indeed, considering the following types:

```
interface A {}
interface B extends A { }
interface C extends A { }
interface D extends B, C { }
```

They can be seen like that:

- `A == B | C | D`
- `D == B & C`

But they don't share the same common usages.

#### Union types

> "A union type definition will specify which of a number of permitted primitive types may be stored in its instances", *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type)*.

Common use cases:

- "Nullable" : `T | null`, combined with `strictNullChecks` [compiler option](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).
- List of primitive values: `'A' | 'B' | 'C'` (instead of `string`)

  - Redux action names
  - Output of `keyof T`
  - ...

#### Intersection types

Not to confuse with [mathematical set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Intersections).

> "[In structural subtyping], the structure of two types determines whether or not one is a subtype of the other", *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Subtyping_schemes)*.

Intersection types are not very common in everyday code:

- They are mostly used by the TypeScript language service / the "IntelliSense".
- It's more common/readable to combine 2 interfaces:

  - with another interface: `interface A extends B, C {}`
  - rather than with an intersection type: `type A = B & C;`
- It can be used with an object mixin function that combine 2 objects, like [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). See [TypeScript Deep Dive > Type System > Intersection Type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html#intersection-type).